Struggling with Task Completion UI in Android App (Task List)
I'm working on an Android app for research, and I'm encountering an issue with implementing a task completion feature. Here's what I need:
The user selects a task.
A QR code reader pops up.
When the correct QR code is scanned, a "Task Complete" message should appear.
After completion, the app should return to the main page, displaying a list of tasks.
The completed task should be marked with a strike-through and greyed-out text.
I've tried both inbuilt checkboxes and a custom implementation for this, but neither approach is working as expected. Does anyone have suggestions on how to properly implement this? I have managed to implement QR code reading functionality and having the completed popup showing up but the task is not being marked completed on home page (i.e. just being displayed normally).
Thanks in advance!
Here is my code for reference:
TaskElement
package com.example.syncops

import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
// Data class to represent a task with a unique ID, name, and completion status
@Parcelize
data class TaskElement(
    // Unique identifier for the task
    val taskId: String,

    // Name or description of the task
    val taskName: String,

    // Indicates whether the task is completed or not (default is false)
    var completed: Boolean = false
) : Parcelable

TaskViewModel:
package com.example.syncops
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class TaskViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository = TaskRepository()

    // Initialize tasks as a SnapshotStateList for observable updates
    private val _tasks = mutableStateListOf<TaskElement>().apply { addAll(repository.getTasks()) }

    // Expose tasks as a read-only list
    val tasks: List<TaskElement> get() = _tasks

    private var trackingJob: Job? = null

    fun startTracking(taskId: String) {
        trackingJob?.cancel()
        trackingJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (isActive) {
                collectAndStoreData(taskId)
                delay(60 * 1000)
            }
        }
    }

    fun stopTracking() {
        trackingJob?.cancel()
        trackingJob = null
    }

    private suspend fun collectAndStoreData(taskId: String) {
        println("Collecting data for task ID: $taskId")
    }

    fun completeTask(task: TaskElement) {
        val index = _tasks.indexOfFirst { it.taskId == task.taskId }
        if (index != -1) {
            // Update the state list using SnapshotStateList methods
            _tasks.removeAt(index)
            _tasks.add(index, task.copy(completed = true))
        }
        stopTracking()
    }
}

TaskListScreen
package com.example.syncops

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TaskListView(taskViewModel: TaskViewModel) {
    val tasks = taskViewModel.tasks

    // Access context within composable scope
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text("Task List") }
        )

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(tasks) { task ->
                TaskListItem(
                    task = task,
                    onTaskClick = {
                        // Only start tracking and open QR code scanner if the task is not completed
                        if (!task.completed) {
                            taskViewModel.startTracking(task.taskId)
                            context.startActivity(
                                Intent(context, QrCodeScannerActivity::class.java).apply {
                                    putExtra("task_id", task.taskId)
                                    putExtra("task_name", task.taskName)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskListItem(task: TaskElement, onTaskClick: () -> Unit) {
    val taskColor = if (task.completed) Color.Gray else Color.Black
    val taskDecoration = if (task.completed) TextDecoration.LineThrough else TextDecoration.None

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .clickable { onTaskClick() },
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        // Non-interactive Checkbox to show completion status
        Checkbox(
            checked = task.completed,
            onCheckedChange = null // Non-interactive
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp)) // Space between checkbox and text

        // Task text with appropriate color and decoration
        Text(
            text = task.taskName,
            color = taskColor,
            textDecoration = taskDecoration,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
    }
}


Where is completeTask being called? What does QrCodeScannerActivity do to the state of your app? Does it return anything? Also, why the hassle with a separate activity for reading the QR code? Why isn't it just a simple composable that updates the view model when the code was read?
